# Prevent duplicate field in database

Tags: database, mongodb, api, unique

I need to create an api to create an entity which must have a unique name in it's data.

exp:

```
{
 name: "Reza",
 ...
}
```

The question is how to throw and error of that name is already taken.
I can handle it by reading the whole table and check if there is no object with that name and then  create the entity, but what can I do with concurrency?
if someone else calls the create api in the same time and the same name it's not in db yet, then I can't notice it's a duplicate name, then we encounter a duplication.
The project is on a baas and the service uses a mongodb but i don't access it directly, and because of sharding I can't use unique indexing.
any workaround for this situations?

Comment: Maybe you can use [unique indices](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/)?

Comment: @Julia The project is on a baas and the service uses a mongodb but i don't access it directly, and because of sharding I can't use unique indexing

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the already found names in the db in an array , and compare the name that is being inserted. I will post this code that checks wether the app name that is being inserted to the db if available and render it some where else , you can benefit from the concept.

```
const updateAppNames = async () => {
    let apps = await purchaseFromAppObjectModel.find({}).sort({ name: 1 });
    const availableApps = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= apps.length; i++) {
      try {
        const obj = apps[i];
        const appName = obj.appName;
        if (availableApps.includes(appName)) {
          console.log("This app exists :", appName);
        } else {
          console.log("This  app does not exist :", appName);
          availableApps.push(appName);
          console.log(availableApps);
        }
      } catch {
        console.error();
      }
    }
    return availableApps;
  };
```

result :

```
This  app does not exist : com.xxx
[ 'com.xxx' ]
This  app does not exist : com.xxy
[ 'com.xxx', 'com.xxy' ]
This app exists : com.xxx
This app exists : com.xxx
This  app does not exist : any game
[ 'com.xxx', 'com.xxy', 'any game' ]
This app exists : any game
This app exists : any game
This app exists : any game
This app exists : any game
This  app does not exist : any.any.any
[
  'com.xxx',
  'com.xxy',
  'any game',
  'any.any.any'
]
This app exists : any.any.any
This app exists : any.any.any
This app exists : any.any.any
```